# Java OpenGL draw a star

Tags: java, opengl, drawing, shapes

I'm working on an OpenGL project in which I want to draw a star. It doesn't necessarily have to be a 3d looking star (2d looking is fine). I have the xyz coordinates for the center of the star and I know the size I'd like it to be. I don't do much OpenGL/3d math programming, so any help here would be much appreciated.

EDIT: More detail: I'm not sure if this is possible but can I draw a 2D looking star at some point in 3d space? I tried simple with a square and tried something like:

```
gl.glTranslated(x, y, z);
gl.glBegin(GL.GL_QUADS);
gl.glVertex2D(x-size,y-size);
gl.glVertex2D(x-size,y+size);
gl.glVertex2D(x+size,y+size);
gl.glVertex2D(x+size,y-size);
gl.glEnd();
```

The square did not seem to be at the correct depth even though I translated to the x,y,z. It appeared to be closer to the front of the screen than it should be. Is it possible to translate a 2d shape in 3d like this?

thanks,

Jeff

Comment: please provide what you have so far and specify what exactly is giving you trouble. Nobody is going to write the whole program for you

Comment: Jonathan, I'm not looking for someone to write the whole program for me, but I should've been more clear. I've added some additional detail.

Comment: Sounds like you might have been using an orthographic projection, rather than a perspective projection.

Comment: Drew, thanks. I'll read up more on the matrices and be back to upvote if this is the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with the 3d drawing and it looks like the translation was actually already done for me and I didn't need to retranslate. So in fact I was translating away from the point. Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 3):

Did you set up your [projection matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_projection#Perspective_projection)? If not, it is probably set to identity, which means the z values of your vertices will have no effect on their rendered positions in screen space. To get the sense of depth you want, you need to create a perspective projection matrix. You can use glFrustum() to create your projection matrix. Here's an example (from [Wikipedia's OpenGL page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opengl)):

```
glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );      /* Subsequent matrix commands will affect the projection matrix */
glLoadIdentity();                   /* Initialise the projection matrix to identity */
glFrustum( -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1000 ); /* Apply a perspective-projection matrix */
```

There are a ton of free OpenGL tutorials online, so you shouldn't have any trouble finding more info.

Comment: Interesting. (FYI I'm working inside the NASA WorldWind application). However, if I do something like gluSphere(...) the sphere does draw in the correct place. I'll readup more on the matrices, thanks!